# Generating Vector of Random Number (of Size M) from -K to K in C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

Is there a fast way to do that?

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Also, just how random do your numbers need to be?

Comment: Do you care if the `M` numbers are unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could do this with [rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/):

```
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
{
  v.push_back(rand()%(2*K)-K;
}
```

But I need to know more about your question. Is the interval [-K,K] or (-K,K)? Do you include -K and K or not?

Comment: Using modulus biases the result, if the size of the output interval does not evenly divide `RAND_MAX`.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Keep that in mind, neversaint. For smaller K it will be less biased, but when you get closer to the max value for rand, you'll really mess things up!

Comment: Minor point, but you may want to v.reserve( M ); before the loop, so the vector doesn't realloc over and over until it is big enough. (which in most cases the capacity will have grown to larger than M)

Comment: @JoshD: Thanks. Yes -K and K  in included.

Comment: And `rand` is often a horrible random number generator. Don't use it.

Comment: @KSchmidt: Another good point. (Though I didn't even declare v :) ). This will save you log(M) reallocations, which is always a good decision!

Comment: @Turtle: it might be suitable if he isn't using this for sensitive stuff. He did say quickly... I wish he'd give more details, though.

Comment: @caf/JoshD: if someone cared, easy to do something like `max = INT_MAX / K * K; for (...) { while ((r = rand()) >= MAX) /* nop */; v.push_back(r % (2*k) - k); }`

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using the [Mersenne Twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html) to generate uniform random variables.  If you generate a uniform deviate u ~ [0,1] then  (2 * K) * u - K will be ~ [-K, K].

Comment: I think some uniformed deviates go to the private school near here.